# How can I decrease playback speed of the video using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I'm coding like this for HTML5, and it's working fine.

```
<video id="video" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" name="media"><source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('video').playbackRate+=0.1">playbackRate+=0.1</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('video').playbackRate-=0.1">playbackRate-=0.1</button><br>
```

for JWplayer, how can I speed down/up playback speed just like above?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4",
        title: "test",
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        autostart: true,
        autoplay: true,
    });

    jwplayer("myElement").onTime(function(time){
        showComments(Math.round(time.position));
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [this post](http://www.longtailvideo.com/blog/33860/slow-motion-with-jw-player/) JW Player support control over playback speed only when it is in `html5` render mode and it that case you can control it through options of the video tag it renders. It would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changePlaybackRate(rateChange) {
        if (jwplayer().getRenderingMode() == "html5") {
            var videoTag = document.querySelector('video');
            if (videoTag.playbackRate) {
                videoTag.playbackRate += rateChange;
            }
        }

        //Small hack to work around a Firefox bug    
        if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) {
            jwplayer().seek(jwplayer().getPosition());
        }
    };
</script>

<button onclick="changePlaybackRate(0.1)">playbackRate+=0.1</button>
<button onclick="changePlaybackRate(-0.1)">playbackRate-=0.1</button>
```

There is not support in JW Player for playback speed control when the browser doesn't support it nativly through HTML5 (for example in case of using Flash player)

Comment: It seems that you are trying to work it on HTML5 video player since you are using `html5` and `'video'` in your code

Comment: @tpeczec Sorry about that! It's working but only on Safari not FireFox. Is it impossible to do it on FireFox?

Comment: @MKK As I have explained jwplayer doesn't have support for this option in other mode then `html5` and through `video` tag it is rendering - as also described in post I have linked to my answer. Now the code should work in FireFox (this is what the fix is for) can you check the `navigator.userAgent` value?

Comment: That's right. I've just noticed that you mentioned about that. Thanks!! Is it easy to switch to html5 render mode just like by addding mode attribute? or Do I need to do all over again? Or completely impossible to do it on FireFox?

Comment: @MKK It all should be automatic (if the browser has proper support) since JW6.

Comment: It's weird. I do have `jwplayer.flash.swf`, `jwplayer.html5.js`,and `jwplayer.js` so it should be html5 render, right? but your code didn't work on FireFox:(

Comment: @MKK Weird indeed, I just have retested it here and seems to be working fine... Did you go through debbuger through the code to see what steps it takes? You might also try setting `videoTag.defaultPlaybackRate` as well but that shouldn't be the reason.

Comment: Did you try it on FireFox? Your code works perfect on all the browser except FireFox.

Comment: @tpeczec I found one interesting thing! I copied whole code from here http://demo.longtailvideo.com/slowmo/  its Slow motion works on FireFox on that page but not my copied page. It seems that it's not rendering with HTML5 mode in my server only when accessed from my FireFox:( Because it renders with HTML5 mode if I access with Safari. Do you have any idea?

Comment: ahhh I tested to play it with slow motion on FireFox. If it's webm file, it's possible but if it's mp4, it was impossible. Is this the answer!? It's totally impossible to play mp4 video file with slow motion on FireFox?

Comment: @MKK The MP4 video support on FireFox is not built into the browser (like for example in Safari) but relies on support from the OS or hardware (so it will behave different depending on client machine). Here you can find a summary table for video formats support in main browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: Thanks! Now everything makes sense:) Thanks for total support! I appreciate it!